# How to avoid whole layout updating with scrolling textview?

Tags: android, performance

I haver a master-detail view with scrolling labels (master textview can be too long to be displayed).

So I've run Depeloper option & enabled Layout updates. If there is a scrolling item the whole screen is constantly refreshing. Is it possible to restrict updates only for this textview?

EDIT:

Let me explain a little bit more. I've enabled View Updating option in developer menu in my phone (it flashed regions on the screen which are updating), installed debug apk and notice that with 3 items in the list - one of them is scrolling horizontally) - the whole display is updating.

Is there any trick to avoid it?

Comment: Not possible.. And why is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand the question correctly but if you mean horizontal scrolling, then this seems to work for me:

```
<TextView
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

If you refer to vertical scrolling, then wrapping your layout in a ScrollView should do.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loong text..."
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Otherwise, please post some code explaining your issue.

Comment: I already have a scrolling, so I've edited my question with additional explanations.